# Flash AS3 Error 1180 - Passing text between frames

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to flash and I'm stuck with a program that I am trying to write. Basically, I want the user to type text into a box in frame 2 and then that text will show up in frame 6. However, I keep getting this error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 6, Line 16 1180: Call to a possibly
>   undefined method myData.

Here is the code on frame 2:

```
var myData:String; stepper1.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,myHandler);
function myHandler(evt:Event):void {  myData = stepper1.text; }
```

And the code on frame 6:

```
output1.text = myData(stepper1.text);
```

Comment: Quit writing code on the timeline and read some more on the document class: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/

Answer (score 0):

myData is defined as a string not as a function.  Have you tried:

```
output1.text = myData;
```